# Node.js - start a process (firebase emulators) and read its output

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to start firebase emulators before Jest tests.

Execute this, but programatically:

```
E:\my-projct>firebase emulators:start --only firestore
i  emulators: Starting emulators: firestore
i  firestore: Serving ALL traffic (including WebChannel) on http://localhost:8080
!  firestore: Support for WebChannel on a separate port (8081) is DEPRECATED and will go away soon. Please use port above instead.
i  firestore: Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
+  firestore: Emulator started at http://localhost:8080
i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
+  All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

Therefore, I need to:

- Execute the command
- Wait for the "All emulators started" string to appear.

How do I read the output?

I have tried the following, all it prints is a newline.

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const child = cp.exec('firebase emulators:start --only firestore');
child.stdout.addListener('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is exactly why we have made the `firebase emulators:exec` command.

So let's say you use "npm run test" to run your Jest scripts, you would use:

```
firebase emulators:exec "npm run test"
```

This will:

1. Start the emulators and wait till they're ready
2. Run your script (`npm run test` in this case)
3. Wait for your script to exit
4. Cleanly shut down the emulators

Comment: Is it possible to debug tests running under emulator:exec?