# how to run Firebase Emulator and Perform Testing using the same npm script?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js, firebase-tools

sorry I am new in node and backend development. so I am trying to perform testing using mocha and firebase emulator to test my cloud function.

currently to perform a test, the sequence is like this:

**1 .** start the emulator using `firebase emulators:start`

**2 .** in different terminal tab, I run the test using npm script `npm run test-cloud-functions`

the script in package.json is like this

```
"scripts": {

   "test-cloud-functions": "export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=\"localhost:8080\" && mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/cloud_function_tests --recursive --extension .test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit",

},
```

**3 .** stop the firebase emulator by pressing control + C

I want those 3 steps above is done in one single npm script. how to do that?

I have tried to add the `firebase emulators:start` to the script like this

```
    "scripts": {
    
       "test-cloud-functions": "firebase emulators:start && export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=\"localhost:8080\" && mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/cloud_function_tests --recursive --extension .test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit",
   
    },
```

but it doesn't work, it doesn't run the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

In npm script under serve:dev, mention the code given below:

```
"serve:dev": "concurrently \"npm run build:dev\" \"firebase emulators:start --only functions\""
```

For more details, refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/robisim74/firebase-functions-typescript-starter/blob/master/functions/package.json).

Option 2:

For integrating the commands `firebase emulators:start` and `npm run test-cloud-functions` follow the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335186/node-js-start-a-process-firebase-emulators-and-read-its-output).